# Doxygen requirements tracking / inverse matrix

Tags: tracking, doxygen, requirements

I use a custom Doxygen tag to track requirement implementations in my software source code, like so :

```
/// @req REQ-BLAH-0010
```

The @req tag is defined in my doxygen.conf file:

```
ALIASES += "req=\xrefitem req \"Requirement\" \"Requirements\" "
```

This works, Doxygen generates a list of requirements for each method/class/file. But sometimes the same requirement number is used in different places, and I'd like a way to get the inverse list: for each requirement number, list all the places in which it is tracked.

Is this possible to do using Doxygen? If so, how? If not, what tool would you recommend for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years ago, I did something like this using a Perl program to process my source-code.

Comment: For lack of a better solution, I set up Doxygen to output XML files as well as HTML, and wrote a quick and dirty Python script to process the XML files and generate both traceability matrices in CSV format.