# Requirement traceability between IBM DOORS and Doxygen generated document

Tags: doxygen, ibm-doors

Recently, we've been experimenting with Doxygen for our document generation and we are able to generate API document out of C & C# source files. Now, we've identified a special case where we should create & link requirement traceability matrix from Doxygen to IBM DOORS document. We've the Requirement Specification defined in DOORS.
I am wondering Is there a way to link the requirements in DOORS to our API document generated by Doxygen.
Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Note: We are using Doxygen v.1.8.19 on windows platform

Thanks,
Badri

Comment: An example regarding the doors document and the corresponding doxygen  source as well as the exact links required. On stack exchange there are also a number of questions regarding requirements and doxygen (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854034/doxygen-requirements-tracking-inverse-matrix) please have a look.

Comment: @albert thanks for the quick response.
I further explored on the similar topic and found the below link that gives more info on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen)

Still,  I'm looking for a solution on traceability matrix where one can verify directly whether all the requirements are mapped or anything missing.. a kind of pulling all IDs in a CSV and mapping etc..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you enough, but in case DOORS is installed on the computer of the users who view the generated document, you can add a link to a DOORS object. To get the URL, right-click on the object and choose "Copy URL".  Or you can generate the link yourself. It is built like this:

doors://mscnbook:36677/?version=2&prodID=0&urn=urn:telelogic::1-52f965671e816bef-O-8-0001fb21

In this case "doors:" is the protocol, "mscnbook" is the name (or FQDN or IP-Address) of the DOORS server, 36677 is the port where the database runs, 52f965671e816bef is the ID of the database, O-8 references an object with the absolute number 8 and 0001fb21 is the ID of the module.

If you have installed a DWA server, you can also generate a link with the http or https protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I further explored on the similar topic and found the below link that gives more info on this.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen)
Now, I am able to establish a link from Doxygen to DOORS document, but still not from DOORS to Doxygen. I'm looking for a solution on traceability matrix where one can verify directly whether all the requirements are mapped or anything missing..

Comment: I have not worked with Doxygen, but perhaps you can create external links from DOORS to the outside, and in DOORS create a filter to show all that don't have an external link, that's how I do traceability matrices usually

Comment: Thanks Mike. I was busy with other projects and couldn't try these options. So,  I am thinking  "Is there any script(may be python or something else) that can create external link from DOORS to outside. I think, this way links can be established. If you provide any sample/link that would be great! Thanks.